# Two NavigationBar Showing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Hi I am new to Swift and am trying to build an app with multiple Views..

My first View(initial view) is embedded in navigation controller.
My Second View is embedded in Tab Bar Controller
My Third View is again embedded in a Navigation Controller.

The problem is that on my third view I see to navigation Controller with the top one taking me back to First View and the below one taking me to Second View.

Is it an incorrect way of doing this? I want to get rid of navigation bar that came from 1st view.

Thanks in anticipation.

PS : I had initially not attempted Navigation Bar on 3rd View.. but the problem was that I am also not able to map Bar Button Item and hence to embed the 3rd View too in a separate Navigation Controller
While it shows perfect in Xcode.. it shows 2 NavBar on the simulator
[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: please share the transition code.

Comment: Remove the second navigation controller. Driectly embed tabcontroller to the 3rd viewcontroller

Comment: If I do that I am not able to add a Menu Item on NavBar of 3rd ViewController

Comment: before presenting the 3rd viewController, just hide the NaviagtionController of first one. it will solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an elegant solution but still this can solve your problem. On your controller embed to `UITabBarController` where you have added **Next Button**. Add the below code on that controller class.

On `ViewWillappear` add show nav bar and on `viewDidDisappear` hide nav bar as shown in below code

ON **viewWillAppear**:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
self.navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = false
}
```

ON **viewDidDisappear**:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}
```